# Conditions for a LP to be integral

Tags: linear-programming

What are the conditions to be met by a LP that allows to infer that its optimum solution will be integral? 
Is total unimodularity a necessary and/or sufficient condition? 
What if all variables are binary?

Answer (score 0):

Total unimodularity is a sufficient condition. To see that there are probably no interesting general necessary conditions (except trivial necessary conditions like no equality has coefficients that are linearly independent over the rationals, unless 0 is a solution), note that you can take ANY set of integer points and take the convex hull, and the set of equations/inequalities that define this arbitrary convex hull will give you constraints for a linear program where an optimal solution can be assumed to only have integer entries.